# Proof of weak Mordell-Weil Theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am studying *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by Silverman and Tate. They only prove the weak Mordell-Weil Theorem in the case when the curve $y^2=f(x)$ has a point of order $2$, i.e., $f(x)$ has a rational root. This means $f(x)$ is reducible, so I suppose it's a quite special case. The authors say the general case needs some knowledge about ideal class group and units. However all the proofs I can find (for example the proof in the other book by Silverman) seem to also use group cohomology or something similar.

1. Is there a proof that resembles the proof in Silverman and Tate? Namely, if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ and we view $E:y^2=f(x)$ as a curve over $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (so that we have the $2$-isogeny), can we define a suitable map from $E(K)$ to $K^*/(K^*)^2$ and show that $E(K)/E(K)^2$ is finite? Maybe instead of $K^*$ we should use the group of fractional ideals? It seems like the same proof goes through in case $K$ has class number $1$, although that may be rare.
2. The authors motivate the $2$-isogeny from $E:y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$ to $\overline{E}:y^2=x^3-2ax^2+(a^2-4b)x$ using uniformization by Weierstrass $\wp$ function; it ultimately comes from cutting the fundamental region of the lattice in half. But since lattices correspond bijectively with elliptic curves in Weierstrass normal form, shouldn't this work for *all* elliptic curves, not just those with rational roots?

Comment: Chapter VIII.1 of Silverman's other book gives a proof without (explicitly) using group cohomology. He then later reproves it using group cohomology - and Silverman's book is really fantastic if you're seeing group cohomology for the first time.

Comment: Regarding point 2, yes you get an isogeny for all elliptic curves, but note that these two curves have a point $(0,0)$ of order $2$ that is defined over the field of definition of the curve, which is $\mathbb Q(a,b)$. If you start instead with $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, the 2-torsion points may live in degree 3 extensions, so you can't get the normal form $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$ without changing the field you're working over.